# Load .so / JNI from Assets on Android 7 / Android N

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-7.0-nougat

I'm looking for a soluton to load .so files using the System.load() method from Assets.

I found a solution that I can read the .so file form AssetManager, save it to the Context.getFilesDir, and load it view System.load().

But this works only below Android 7. 
On Android 7, I get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "<AppDir>"
needed or dlopened by "/vendor/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not
accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
```

Actually I would like to load libcrypto.so via System.loadLibrary, which works like a charm for e.g. on Samsung devices, without embedid my own libcrypto.so. But for some devices, like Huawei, I need to include my own libcrypto.so - which would be fine, but on some Samsung devices, it causes kernel panik If I use my own libcrypto.so, while the device has its on (on Android 6).

Btw, Huawei has its on pre-build libcrypto.so, but when I'm tring to load that one, again, I'm getting this:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library

```
"/system/lib/libcrypto.so" needed or dlopened by "/vendor/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
```

I know Android 7.0 has some new security features regarding to native libraries, went through the guide, but I found nothing that can help me finding a workaround.

Any help would be appriciated.